# How can I detect that my site is being visited in the Google Search App?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-applications, detection

I have a site that delivers PDF output in a new browser tab, using a link similar to:

```
<a href='https://example.com/report1234' target='_blank'>click</a>
```

A friend observed that the PDF doesn't load in Google's Search App for iOS, which instead just reloads the original page.

I'd like to either modify the behavior in the Search App, or suggest that the user go to Chrome or Mobile Safari instead.

However, I have been unable to find any documentation that helps me to differentiate between Google Search and the Chrome app. I appreciate any thoughts!